# swagger : basic authentication not working

Tags: rest, swagger

Here my swagger.yaml :

```
...
paths:
 /api/geocode:
  get:
  ....
responses:
    200:
      description: "OK"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ResourcesOfGeocodingInformation"
    204:
      description: "Pas de résultat"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ResourcesOfGeocodingInformation"
    401:
      description: "Unauthorized"
    403:
      description: "Forbidden"
    404:
      description: "Not Found"
    500:
      description: "Erreur technique"
    504:
      description: "Via Michelin ne répond pas "
  security:
  - basicAuth: []
  x-swagger-router-controller: "Geocode"
  securityDefinitions:
   basicAuth:
    type: "basic"
definitions:
...
```

But when i try to request this WS without authentication this is working and give me a 200 status. 
What's wrong?

Comment: Does your backend actually implement Basic auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because Swagger does not enforce security and only gives information about it in the swagger docs. You need to add basic Auth to your service.

> A declaration of the security schemes available to be used in the specification. This does not enforce the security schemes on the operations and only serves to provide the relevant details for each scheme.

Refer to this for more details: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#securityDefinitionsObject

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to indent properly. Since you've done everything stated in the documentation. Have you tried to "secure" the whole docs with a root-level `security` assignment?

```
securityDefinitions:
  basicAuth:
    type: basic

# To apply Basic auth to the whole API:
security:
  - basicAuth: []
```

Like this.

Comment: Same, still 200 status :/